# Passing (and using) parameters to the "new" action of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My app has Lessons which have many Drills.

When I am looking at a lesson I want to be able to create new Drills and automatically assign their lesson_id.

So far what I have is a link in the lesson's show.html.erb that passes in the lesson's id, like so:

```
<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
          new_drill_path(lesson_id: @lesson.id), :class => 'btn' %>
```

This adds the lesson_id to the params hash.  I figured out how to pass the param into the drill by doing this in my controller:

```
  def new
    @drill = Drill.new
    params.each do |key, value|
      method = key.to_s + '='
      method.to_sym
      if @drill.respond_to? method
        @drill.send method, value
      end
    end
  end
```

However, this code seems smelly to me. It seems like there ought to be a more rails-y way to do it, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). Something like this:

```
# in config/routes.rb
resources :lessons do
  resources :drills
end
```

That'll give you nested URLs/routes, and route helpers like `lesson_drills_path` that take a `Lesson`-record as its argument to produce a path like `/lessons/:lesson_id/drills`.

Your `DrillsController` will therefore have access to `params[:lesson_id]` because it'll be given in the URL. That means that you can do things like

```
# POST /lesson/:lesson_id/drills/
def create
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
  @drill = @lesson.drills.new(params[:drill])
  if @drill.save
    ..
  else
    ..
  end
end
```

See more in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24579/rails-3-create-method-with-association/24609#24609) over on CodeReview, and check the links in there too

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but read up on Nested Resources. Your new action should look something like:

```
def new
  @lesson = Book.find(params[:lesson_id])
  @drill = @lesson.drills.build
end
```